# Indy socket error

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe5

Динамически создаю IdHTTP, выполняю POST-запрос на свой php-скрипт. Source example:

```
http := TIdHTTP.Create(Nil);
try
  sl.add('name=value');
  try
    html.Text := http.Post('http://page.ru', sl);
  finally
    http.Free();
  end;
except
  on E: EIdException do
  begin
    // исключение
  end;
end;
```

У одного из пользователей программы регулярно вылетают такие эксепшены:

> Socket Error # 10038 Socket operation on non-socket.
>
> Socket Error # 10038 Socket operation on non-socket.
>
> Socket Error # 10004 Interrupted system call.
>
> Socket Error # 10004 Interrupted system call.

Описание на MSDN почитал, а как решить - непонятно. Требуется помощь!

Comment: Версия Delphi XE5

Comment: Лучше приведите часть реального кода. Или это и есть MCVE, который тоже вызывает исключение? Что у этого пользователя с файрволлом?

Comment: @kami, по его утверждению фаерволл отключен. Эти ошибки возникают не каждый раз, а в случайный момент.

Comment: @kami, реальный код приводить нет смысла - там почти всё то же самое. Класс TLicense для проверки лицензии пользователя по hwid компьютера. В начале гет-запрос на проверку application last version и далее post-запрос, в котором передается hwid+control_header, накрытые по des\aes. А в ответ либо код ошибки, либо положительный ответ и требуемые для работы приложения сигнатуры

Comment: Приведенный код вызывает исключение?

Comment: @zed, да, именно так :(

Comment: Значит, проблема в чём-то другом, но не в этом коде.

Comment: @zed, понять бы в чём. Кроме экземпляра IdHTTP более ни через что с сетью не работаю в этом приложении(

Comment: Попрбуйте использовать не инди а Synapse, я гарантирую что ошибка пропадет, тоже пишу вернее написал подобную прогу с проверкой лицухи и т.д

Comment: Спасибо, давно подумываю. От такого решения пока останавливало то, что придется штудировать документацию, переделывать обработку исключений =((